# Workaround for IE's document.all.table.rows() 'function'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome-extension, html-table

I have a script on a website that has been coded for IE. I can't edit the original script, so i'm trying to alter it through js and Jquery (by using a Chrome Plugin).

The script uses next line to add a row to an HTML-table, but gives errors in Chrome:

```
document.all.tbl.rows(i);
```

after some research I found out this is a function only used in IE. In Chrome an array is used.
So all these lines should be altered to the following:

```
document.all.tbl.rows[i]
```

The same problem occurs with `rows[i].cells()`.

I've tried moving the array to `rowsData` and overwriting `rows` to a function retrieving the data from `rowsData`.

```
document.all.tbl.rowsData = document.all.tbl.rows; // This seems to work
document.all.tbl.rows = function(id) {
    console.log('This function is used');
}
```

After checking with Chrome's devtools, I've found that rowsData does contain a copy of rows, but rows is still an array. When using `document.all.tbl.rows()` I still get the same error:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.all.tbl.rows is not a function

The only other option is replacing the entire function (which is quite long, and not preferred because there's always a probability it can change).

I'm guessing that overriding a browser variable isn't possible.
Is there some way I can make this work?

Comment: To override class functions you need to do it on the prototype: `HTMLTableElement.prototype.rows`

Comment: still doesn't seem to work. I've recreated what I'm talking about on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yh7pgz3t/1/